# Development board with cellular capabilities smaller than Arduino

Tags: arduino, gsm, board

I would like to build my own cellphone (phone calls and texts at least).

Having experience with Arduino, I found several [cellular shields](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9607) and libraries that could allow me to do so with Arduino.

However, this would make my phone pretty big (for a phone) as it would be the size of the arduino plus the shield.

Is there any smaller alternative for this?

I know a lot of development boards exist, and some of them are smaller (even Arduino mini for example), the only problem is I can't find one that has (or can have via a module) cellular capabilities in small size.

(and unfortunately I need to find something not too expensive of course)

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you have to accept that your device will be bigger and more expensive than a comparable cellphone.

If you want to assemble something out of modules, you're already at the smallest point. To get smaller, you'll have to do your own PCB and attach a suitable GSM module and microcontroller. (You can get programmable modules which may suffice: Sierra Wireless "Open AT" for example)

Comment: I understand there isn't much that can be done, but using for example a "raw" module (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10138)? I can't understand if these are also programmable or if I need a board with it (arduino mini)?

Comment: @Matthieu I'm sure you can interface to it with an Arduino mini or any micro. It sounds like any micro with a serial port will sufice.

Comment: Yes, you'll need a microcontroller to do the "user interface". Then it just sends a set of AT commands to say "make call", "answer call", "send text message" etc.

Comment: Other important thing to watch for: power supply requirements. It may work directly from a Lithium battery, but the internal resistance of the battery may be too high.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this board:
[GBoard](http://store.iteadstudio.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=50_51&products_id=537).

For $55 you get an Arduino with build-in SIM900 and more, in a (relatively) small form-factor.

Never used it myself, but I bought a GSM shield from these guys, and I'm happy with its production quality.

The biggest drawback I see for this board (and the reason I didn't use it myself) is the lack of a USB port.

Comment: Wow amazing, this is really interesting thank you! As for the lack of USB it shouldn't be a problem for me.